# MySQL ORDER BY proprity

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT camp_id, 
(target_countries REGEXP "US") AS ranking,
(target_states REGEXP "FL") AS state_ranking
FROM run_camps
WHERE served < total
AND ((target_countries LIKE "%US%") OR target_countries = "")
AND ((target_states LIKE "%FL%") OR target_states = "")
ORDER BY ranking DESC,
state_ranking DESC,
last_click ASC,
priority DESC
LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, there are 4 "columns" sorting the results. However, I'm trying to give the column "priority" more priority than any of the others.

Tried putting the priority DESC before the ranking, but that doesn't work. Should I create a second query within that one to sort the results from the first query again but now with "priority DESC" as a unique ORDER BY column?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Some sample data (omitting some columns for space):

```
camp_id | target_countries | target_states | total | served | priority | last_click
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1234  |       US         |     FL        | 10000 |  5000  |    0     |2015-03-06 01:00:00
  1235  |       US         |     FL        | 10000 |  5000  |   10     |2015-03-06 02:00:00
  1236  |       US         |     FL        | 10000 |  5000  |    0     |2015-03-06 00:00:00
  1237  |       US         |     FL        | 10000 |  5000  |    0     |2015-03-06 00:00:00
  1238  |       US         |     FL        | 10000 |  5000  |    0     |2015-03-06 00:00:00
```

Tried putting the priority DESC right after the ORDER BY, however, I'm not getting camp_id 1235 as the result.

Comment: ORDER BY clauses are evaluated in the order they occur in, that’s how it works. Either you want to sort by that `priority` column first, or you don’t. What you actually want to achieve here is unclear.

Comment: Perhaps sample data and expected results would help.  As is, it's difficult to understand what `doesn't work`...

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I added a few table records as samples.

Comment: With that data and `ORDER BY priority DESC, …` you can only get the 1235 record, everything else is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
ORDER BY ranking DESC,
state_ranking DESC,
last_click ASC,
priority DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Try using:

```
ORDER BY
priority DESC,  
ranking DESC,
state_ranking DESC,
last_click ASC
LIMIT 1
```

As @CBroe wrote in the comment, whatever is listed topmost(or first in the list) is the one that is the results are sorted by first, then the next sort is applied, etc...

Comment: As written, the question is is too broad to really understand.  BTW -- it appears to OP has already tried this solution -- *Tried putting the priority DESC before the ranking, but that doesn't work.*

Comment: That did work actually. For some reason it wasn't working in a testing local server but it is working in my production server. Thanks!